# How to create an "all@domain.com" email list on Microsoft365 that auto-updates to always include all users?

Tags: outlook, microsoft365

I would like to create an "all@mydomain.com" email distribution list, which automatically tracks changes of all users. I am currently aware of 2 approaches, which both don't serve my needs

- Create a Microsoft 365 'group' (which can have a Teams/SharePoint site, etc.)
- Create a 'distribution list'

Problem: Both require me to manually add all users, also in the future when new users join the domain.

How can I make a group/team/list/shared address/alias/... which automatically comprises all user accounts, both now and at any time in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a 3rd option:

- Create a "dynamic distribution list" - which allows to define dynamic conditions who should be in the list

This option is not available from within the "Microsoft 365 admin center", but instead (somewhat hidden) in the "Microsoft Exchange admin center".